# German umlauts encoded incorrectly when submitting with multipart/formdata

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-resource

My VueJS application contains a form which data are submitted like in the following. The data are sent with `Content-Type: multipart/fromdata`.

The problem is that if `email` or `message` contain special characters, such as German umlauts (öäü), they are submitted in a way that looks not quite correct. Plain ASCII characters are submitted correctly.

```
async submit() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("email", this.form.email);
  formData.append("message", this.form.message);
  formData.append("file", this.file, encodeURI(this.file.name));
  await axios.post(
    url,
    formData
  );
}
```

The request payload looks like this:

```
-----------------------------1028947901156719297473081001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

Ã¤
-----------------------------1028947901156719297473081001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

Ã¶
-----------------------------1028947901156719297473081001
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy_01.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: The email in your example looks like an UTF-8 encoded `ä` that is displayed as ISO-8859-1. In what encoding should the fields be transmitted? How are they processed? What is used to display your output?

Comment: According to W3 https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en , they advice to explicitly make the page send UTF-8 encoding, which should be able to detect the german umlauts correctly. So I would try adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your head tag.

Comment: The fields should be transmitted as UTF-8. The backend is a Java REST controller which will store these values in a database.

Comment: @Shilly The head tag already contains `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: You want to transfer UTF-8, what is transfered seems to be UTF-8 so you should check how you receive/process/display the data.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The Java application server receiving the request has a fallback charset of "ascii". That's probaly the reason.